# <JSP>Stuck in the error : "Unterminated &lt;c:forEach tag "

Tags: java, jsp, ibatis

I am working on JSP and stuck in this error "Unterminated <c:forEach tag "

This is relevant part from contentStatis.jsp

```
<tbody>

            <br><c:forEach var="contentStatis" items="${resultcount}" >
                <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.dtm}" /></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.StudentPkg}" /></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.Shared}" /></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.NonShared}" /></td>                

            </tbody>
```

This is the relevant part from Controller.java

```
List<ContentStatis> result = ContentStatisRepository.statis(maps);
List<ContentStatis> resultcount = ContentStatisRepository.mnote(maps);
Pagination<ContentStatis> resultList = PaginationUtil.getPaginationList(result, condition, (long)result.size(), Order.DESC);

model.addAttribute("result", result);
model.addAttribute("condition", condition);
model.addAttribute("resultList", resultList);
model.addAttribute("resultcount", resultcount);         
    }
    return "admin/statisMng/contentStatis";
```

And this is relevant part from the Repository.java

```
    @Statement(id="ContentStatis.mnote")
public List<ContentStatis> mnote(Map<String, Object> maps);
```

Does anyone see where the problem is?
When I execute the jsp, the error occurs

"/WEB-INF/views/admin/statisMng/contentStatis.jsp(459,0) Unterminated <c:forEach tag"

Comment: I would check out [this tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/tags.jsp) for a quick tutorial on tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most jstl tags are block tags so they need to be terminated

either by using `<tag/>` or `<tag></tag>`

```
<c:forEach var="contentStatis" items="${resultcount}" >
    <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.dtm}" /></td>
    <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.StudentPkg}" /></td>
    <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.Shared}" /></td>
    <td align="center"><c:out value="${contentStatis.NonShared}" /></td>   
</c:forEach>  <!-- you are missing this bit -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `</c:forEach>` wrapping the content

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your error is telling you exactly what the problem is. This tag isn't terminated

```
<c:forEach var="contentStatis" items="${resultcount}" >
```

Somewhere you need to add a

```
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to end the

```
<c:forEach>
```

tag, close it with:

```
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's self explanatory:**

```
"/WEB-INF/views/admin/statisMng/contentStatis.jsp(459,0) Unterminated <c:forEach tag"
```

means you need to close the tag. or "terminate" it.